# application:openURL:options: vs scene:openURLContexts:

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk

in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started they say

> iOS 13 moved opening URL functionality to the SceneDelegate. If you are using iOS 13, add the following method to your SceneDelegate so that operations like logging in or sharing function as intended:

```
// SceneDelegate.swift
import FacebookCore
  ...
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else {
        return
    }

    ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
        UIApplication.shared,
        open: url,
        sourceApplication: nil,
        annotation: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
    )
}
```

but when I implement it in `application:openURL:options:` it's still work as expected. So do i really need to implement `scene:openURLContexts:` and why ? what the difference between the 2 functions ?

Comment: When you debug the added code, when you open a url - what functions are being called? is it `scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>)` and then `application:openURL:options:`? Or is it `application:openURL:options:` right away? What happens when you remove the code snippet you wrote above?

Comment: @CloudBalancing for some obvious raison I can not implement scene:openURLContexts: right now (i m on delphi) but I can confirm you that I m under ios 15.7 and that application:openURL:options: is called as expected

Answer (score 1):

I found an interesting [article](https://blogs.halodoc.io/deep-linking-using-url-scheme-in-ios/) which talks about it. Basically, if your app run on up to iOS 13 SceneDelegate is preferable than AppDelegate. In this case, even if you implement `application:openURL:options:`, `scene:openURLContexts:` will be executed instead of `application:openURL:options:`.

Another basic difference between them is that openURLContexts can receive a Set of URLContexts instead of a simple URL, and [URLContext is an object which has metadata besides the URL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscene/connectionoptions/3238068-urlcontexts).

Comment: thanks but it's not what I observe, i m in ios 15.7 and application:openURL:options: is called